# Здание : Вывести слова в предложении обратном порядке ( agrv[1])

Tags: c

Задача - элементарна - вывести слова поданные в виде первого аргумента в обратном порядке.

```
Assignment name  : rev_wstr
Expected files   : rev_wstr.c
Allowed functions: write, malloc, free
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Write a program that takes a string as a parameter, and prints its words in 
reverse order.

A "word" is a part of the string bounded by spaces and/or tabs, or the 
begin/end of the string.

If the number of parameters is different from 1, the program will display 
'\n'.

In the parameters that are going to be tested, there won't be any "additional" 
spaces (meaning that there won't be additionnal spaces at the beginning or at 
the end of the string, and words will always be separated by exactly one space).

Examples:

$> ./rev_wstr "You hate people! But I love gatherings. Isn't it ironic?" | cat -e
ironic? it Isn't gatherings. love I But people! hate You$
$>./rev_wstr "abcdefghijklm"
abcdefghijklm
$> ./rev_wstr "Wingardium Leviosa" | cat -e
Leviosa Wingardium$
$> ./rev_wstr | cat -e
$
$>
```

я над этой задачкой на экзе просидел 2 часа, никак не мог понять почему и что не работает ( выдавал ошибку типо object changed after being freed ( Что, каво?) сейчас запустил в gdb online - работает как швейцарские часы. Делал через стэк, в итоге плюнул и сделал через массив. Но все равно хочу понять почему это не работало на экзе.

```
/* ************************************************************************** */
/*                                                                            */
/*                                                        :::      ::::::::   */
/*   rev_wstr.c                                         :+:      :+:    :+:   */
/*                                                    +:+ +:+         +:+     */
/*   By: exam <marvin@42.fr>                        +#+  +:+       +#+        */
/*                                                +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+           */
/*   Created: 2020/02/21 11:16:21 by exam              #+#    #+#             */
/*   Updated: 2020/02/21 12:53:58 by exam             ###   ########.fr       */
/*                                                                            */
/* ************************************************************************** */

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"

int     ft_isspace(char c);

int     ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;
    while (!(ft_isspace(str[len])))
        len++;
    return (len);
}

int     ft_strlen_full(char *str)
{
    int len;

    len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    return (len);
}


void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    write(1, str, ft_strlen(str));
}

char    *ft_strcpy(char *dest,char *src)
{
    int i;

    i = -1;
    while (src[++i])
        dest[i] = src[i];
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

char    *ft_strdup(char* src)
{
    int len;
    char *out;

    len = ft_strlen(src);
    out = (char*)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    ft_strcpy(out,src);
    return (out);
}

typedef struct s_stack
{
    struct s_stack  *previous;
    char    *str;
}       t_stack;

void    ft_put_in(t_stack **stack,char *str)
{
    t_stack *new;
    new = (t_stack*)malloc(sizeof(t_stack));
    new->str = ft_strdup(str);
    new->previous = (*stack);
    (*stack) = new;
}

char *ft_put_out(t_stack **stack)
{
    char *out;
    t_stack *temp;
    out = ft_strdup((*stack)->str);
    temp = (*stack)->previous;
    free((*stack)->str);
    free(*stack);
    (*stack) = temp;
    return (out);
}

int     ft_isspace(char c)
{
    return (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == 0 );
}

void    ft_print_stack(t_stack *stack)
{
    while (stack)
    {   
        ft_putstr(ft_put_out(&stack));
        if (stack)
        ft_putchar(' ');
    }
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    t_stack *stack;
    int len;

    stack = NULL;
    i = 0;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        len = ft_strlen_full(argv[1]);
        while(i < len)
        {
            while (ft_isspace(argv[1][i]))
                i++;
            if (i >= len)
                break;
            ft_put_in(&stack,&(argv[1][i]));
            i += ft_strlen(&argv[1][i]) + 1;
        }
        ft_print_stack(stack);
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: У меня всё работает. Ещё убрал ненужные копии строки, всё равно пашет.
`char *ft_put_out(t_stack **stack)
{
    char *out;
    t_stack *temp;
    /*out = ft_strdup((*stack)->str);*/
    out = (*stack)->str;
    temp = (*stack)->previous;
    /*free((*stack)->str);*/
    free(*stack);
    (*stack) = temp;
    return (out);
}`

Comment: Есть мнение что это байда характерна для маков. Вы на маке запускаете?

Comment: Я на каноэ не катаюсь. И мак не употребляю. Проверял на ubuntu.

Comment: Буферизированный вывод? Пробовали больше 4 Кбайт на вход дать? Работает?

Comment: А чем обусловлено 4КБ ?